# Append part of 1 match to another match

Tags: awk

I want to turn this...

```
1,g2h4,3gf3,2,2030
,,Dog,8
,,Cat,2
,,Fish,5
34,3fds,ds2f,56,4443
,,Pig,12
,,Cow,9
4,fd6sf,kjl9,88,283
,,Mouse,22
1,kqkjw,jfww32,1,987
,,Hen,1
```

Into this...

```
,,Dog,8,2,2030
,,Cat,2,2,2030
,,Fish,5,2,2030
,,Pig,12,56,4443
,,Cow,9,56,4443
,,Mouse,22,88,283
,,Hen,1,1,987
```

So only output lines that start with ",," with the info from columns 4 and 5 of the last line starting with a number appended to the end.

I came up with this but it doesn't work.

```
awk -F "," '/^[0-9]/ {nid=$4} {tid=$5} /^,,/ {line=$0} {print line","nid","tid}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^[0-9]+/{val=$4 OFS $5;next}{$0=$0 OFS val} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
/^[0-9]+/{
  val=$4 OFS $5
  next
}
{
  $0=$0 OFS val
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{            ##Starting BEGIN section of this code from here.
  FS=OFS=","      ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here for all lines.
}
/^[0-9]+/{        ##Checking condition if a line starts from digits then do following.
  val=$4 OFS $5   ##Creating variable val which has 4th field OFS and 5th field of current line.
  next            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  $0=$0 OFS val   ##Setting value of current line to current line OFS and val variable value here.
}
1                 ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line here.
'  Input_file     ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: You could just do `{print $0, val}` instead of `{
  $0=$0 OFS val
}
1`. That'd improve conciseness and performance since it's fewer steps and awk won't need to re-split the record like it does when you modify `$0`.